# Prolog: How to find all reachable node from a given node?

Tags: prolog

Given facts:

```
edges(a,[b,c]). 
edges(b,[d]).
edges(c,[a]).
edges(d,[e]).
```

For now, I can write following predicate:

```
find(F, L) :- 
    edges(F, Nodes) -> 
    findall([X|Y], (member(X, Nodes), find(X, Y)), L);
    L = [].
```

It works fine when there is no cycle, for example, find(b,L). gives me d and e. But it's not working when cycle exists. So how can I modify my code to handle the cycle? e.g find(c,L) will output a, b, c, d, e as well as find(a,L). 
Any helps are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could opt to use an accumulator to keep track of the nodes you visited. In order to do this you need a list as an additional argument. Since this lists is empty at the beginning of your search, you'd always call the predicate with `[]`, so you might as well hide it by using a calling predicate, let's maybe call it `start_dest/2`:

```
start_dest(S,D) :-
   dif(S,D),                % start and destination nodes are different
   start_dest_(S,D,[]).     % actual relation called with empty accumulator
```

The first goal `dif/2` is only necessary in order to prevent solutions where the start node and the destination node are the same. If you want to permit such solutions just remove that goal. The actual relation will search for reachable nodes by traversing the graph node by node. You can distinguish two cases.

1. If the two nodes are equal you found a possible destination node.
2. If the nodes are different, there has to be to be an intermediate node in the adjacence list of the node you are currently at. The current node must not have been visited in the search so far (to avoid cycles). There has to be a path from the intermediate node to the destination and the current node must not appear in that path, so it has to be added to the list of visited nodes.

You can express these two cases in Prolog like so:

```
start_dest_(D,D,_Visited).        % case 1: destination found
start_dest_(S,D,Visited) :-       % case 2:
   maplist(dif(S),Visited),       % S has not been visited yet
   edges(S,Reachable),            % Reachable is the adjacence list
   member(X,Reachable),           % that has to contain the intermediate node X
   start_dest_(X,D,[S|Visited]).  % there has to be a path from X to D that
                                  % does not include S
```

Your example queries yield the desired result:

```
?- start_dest(b,N).
N = d ;
N = e ;
false.

?- start_dest(c,N).
N = a ;
N = b ;
N = d ;
N = e ;
false.
```

If you remove the first goal (`dif(S,D)`) in `start_dest/2`, you get an additional solution. This corresponds to the view that every node is reachable from itself.

```
?- start_dest(b,N).
N = b ;
N = d ;
N = e ;
false.
```

Note that this predicate can be used in all directions, e.g. *From which nodes can `e` be reached?*:

```
?- start_dest(S,e).
S = a ;
S = b ;
S = c ;
S = d ;
false.
```

Or the most general query: *Which nodes are reachable from any node?*:

```
?- start_dest(S,D).
S = a,
D = b ;
S = a,
D = d ;
S = a,
D = e ;
S = a,
D = c ;
S = b,
D = d ;
S = b,
D = e ;
S = c,
D = a ;
S = c,
D = b ;
S = c,
D = d ;
S = c,
D = e ;
S = d,
D = e ;
false.
```

As opposed to your predicate `find/2`, `start_dest/2` gives you the reachable nodes one at a time. If you want to get all reachable nodes in a list, you can use predicates like `findall/3`, `bagof/3` and `setof/3` as you did in `find/2`, e.g.:

```
?- bagof(N, start_dest(b,N), Reachable).
Reachable = [d, e].

?- bagof(N, start_dest(c,N), Reachable).
Reachable = [a, b, d, e].
```

If you intend to always search for all reachable nodes but do not want to query with `bagof/3` all the time, you can write a calling predicate like:

```
reachable_from(Reachable,Start) :-
   bagof(N, start_dest(Start,N), Reachable).

?- reachable_from(Reachable,Start).
Reachable = [b, d, e, c],
Start = a ;
Reachable = [d, e],
Start = b ;
Reachable = [a, b, d, e],
Start = c ;
Reachable = [e],
Start = d.
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this freaking great algorithm in SWI-prolog's source code.

It's so elegant that I want to share it with you.

This snippet is indeed a BFS algorithm.

```
%!  reachable(+Vertex, +UGraph, -Vertices)
%
%   True when Vertices is  an  ordered   set  of  vertices  reachable in
%   UGraph, including Vertex.  Example:
%
%       ?- reachable(1,[1-[3,5],2-[4],3-[],4-[5],5-[]],V).
%       V = [1, 3, 5]

reachable(N, G, Rs) :-
    reachable([N], G, [N], Rs).

reachable([], _, Rs, Rs).
reachable([N|Ns], G, Rs0, RsF) :-
    neighbours(N, G, Nei),
    ord_union(Rs0, Nei, Rs1, D),
    append(Ns, D, Nsi),
    reachable(Nsi, G, Rs1, RsF).
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possibility :

```
% we get a list of all edges
get_all_edges(Edges) :-
   bagof(edges(X,Y), edges(X,Y), Edges).

% main predicate
find(F, L) :-
    get_all_edges(Edges),
    find(Edges, F, Out),
    % the result you get is for example  [[a, [b, [d, [e|e], [e]]], [c]]]
    flatten(Out, FOut),
    list_to_set(FOut, L).

% no more edges, work is done
find([], L, L).

find(Edges, F, L) :-
     % we get the good nodes
    select(edges(F, Nodes), Edges, Rest)
    -> findall([X|Y], (member(X, Nodes), find(Rest, X, Y)), L)
    ;  L = [].
```

Result :

```
?- find(c, L).
L = [a, b, d, e, c].
```

Answer (score 0):

After you'll have learned the basic way, take a look to what [libraries](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ugraphs) have to offer:

```
?- findall(V-U,(edges(V,Us),member(U,Us)),Es),
   vertices_edges_to_ugraph([],Es,G),
   reachable(a,G,Rs).
Es = [a-b, a-c, b-d, c-a, d-e],
G = [a-[b, c], b-[d], c-[a], d-[e], e-[]],
Rs = [a, b, c, d, e].
```

You could be tempted to go directly from your edges/2 to ugraph format, but better make use of predefined functionality (i.e. vertices_edges_to_ugraph/3)